# How to install Cydia for iOS 11?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm using an iPhone 7 plus device and I updated the software version of my device to the latest iOS 11 version.

Are there public jailbreak steps for iOS 11?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because jailbreaking iOS 11 is out of scope here.

Comment: Jailbreak alone is not out of scope or topic, but it can get close to piracy or warez at times. No need for anyone who objects to answer, but not summarily out of bounds in general or this specific wording presently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I jailbreak?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336229/how-do-i-jailbreak)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because jailbreaking iOS 11 is out of scope here.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no jailbreak available for any build of iOS 11 on any hardware.