# How do I jailbreak an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

<sup>This is a canonical question [Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different)</sup>

How do I jailbreak an iPhone or iPad (to install a package manager like Cydia or Sileo for tweaks) on:

- iOS/iPadOS 13
- iOS 12
- iOS 11
- iOS 10
- iOS 9
- iOS 8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**App-based jailbreaks:** You will have to sideload the .ipa with [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/) or download it from [ignition.fun](https://ignition.fun)(visit this website on your iOS device and go into the jailbreaks section). You will then need to "trust" the profile, then open up the app on your iOS device and click jailbreak.

**Web-based jailbreaks:** You open up the website on your iOS device and click jailbreak.

**Computer-based jailbreaks:** You download the jailbreak app to your computer. Connect your iOS device and click jailbreak on your computer(make sure your device is trusted via iTunes first).

**No substrate/substitute jailbreaks:** These jailbreaks do not support tweaks or Cydia and only give you root access. You may be able to use apps like Filza or NewTerm 2. There are currently no jailbreaks like this.

If any of the links are broken try using the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).

#### All iOS versions are currently jailbreakable

If your device is not supported, see [my answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389597/) about checkra1n, which can jailbreak all iOS versions.

### 11.0 - 13.5

[unc0ver](https://github.com/pwn20wndstuff/Undecimus/releases) (app-based)

### 12.0 - 12.4

[Chimera](https://chimera.sh/) (app-based) (installs [Sileo](https://getsileo.app), a more modern alternative to Cydia)

### 11.0 - 11.4.1

[Electra](https://coolstar.org/electra/) (app-based)

Important: If your device crashes/freezes frequently while using Electra, install Apple Maps.

### 10.0 - 10.3.3 (recommended, 64-bit only)

[Totally-not.spyware.lol](https://totally-not.spyware.lol/) (web-based) (if you are wondering, it is safe, the spyware thing is just a joke)

Important: It will ask you if you want to install doubleH3lix or Meridian if your device supports both. Choose doubleH3lix unless your device doesn't have a headphone jack.

### 10.0 - 10.3.3 (64 bit only, only devices w/ headphone jack)

[doubleH3lix](https://doubleh3lix.tihmstar.net/) (app-based)

### 10.0 - 10.3.3 (all 64 bit devices, use doubleH3lix instead if you can)

[Meridian](https://meridian.sparkes.zone/) (app-based)

### 10.0 - 10.3.3 (32 bit only)

[h3lix](https://h3lix.tihmstar.net/) (app-based)

### 9.3.5 (32 bit only)

[Phoenix](https://phoenixpwn.com/) (app-based)

### 9.3 - 9.3.3 (64 bit only) (recommended)

[jbme.qwertyoruiop.com](https://jbme.qwertyoruiop.com/#) (web-based)

### 9.2 - 9.3.3 (64 bit only)

[Pangu IPA](http://en.pangu.io/) (app-based)

### 9.0 - 9.0.2 (32 bit) 9.0 - 9.1 (64 bit only)

[Pangu9](http://en.9.pangu.io/) (computer-based)

### 9.0 - 9.3.4 (32 bit only) (recommended)

[jailbreak.me](https://jailbreak.me/) (web-based)

### 9.0 - 9.3.4 (32 bit only)

[Home Depot](http://wall.supplies/) (app-based)

### 8.4.1 (32 bit only)

[EtasonJB](https://etasonjb.tihmstar.net/) (app-based)

### 8.0 - 8.4

[TaiG 8.0-8.1.2](http://www.taig.com/en/update_log.html) or [TaiG 8.1.3-8.4](http://www.taig.com/en/) (computer-based)

Answer (score 0):

### [checkra1n](https://checkra.in/) (iOS 12.3+ on most devices up to iPhone X)

- checkra1n requires a device from the iPhone 5S to iPhone X, with the following exceptions:

  - iPad Air 2
  - iPad 5th Gen
  - iPad Pro 1st Gen
- checkra1n requires the device to be put into DFU mode.
- checkra1n requires a device on iOS 12.3 or higher.
- checkra1n requires a Mac to execute the jailbreak.
- The jailbroken state will be lost upon reboot and will not return until the jailbreak utility is ran again.

Answer (score 0):

### All iOS versions (only devices based on A7-A11)

[checkra1n](https://checkra.in) (computer-based)

Notes:

- You can check which proccessor your device is based on by going to its Wikipedia page and checking the "System on Chip" or "System on a Chip" in the sidebar
- checkra1n natively only supports macOS and Linux
- On Windows, you can use [checkn1x](https://asineth.gq/checkn1x/), an extremely barebones OS (only ~100MB) that comes with checkra1n preinstalled

Instructions for checkn1x:

1. Download the correct `.iso` file for your system and flash it to an external drive using a tool like balenaEtcher or Rufus
2. Shut down your computer, and when booting up, select the external drive you just flashed to boot from
3. Wait about a minute for checkn1x to boot up, and follow the prompt shown on your screen to install checkra1n to your iOS device