# Send iMessage from Firefox

Tags: messages, firefox

Ubuntu + Firefox has become my daily driver. I would like to be able to send iMessage from Firefox. I am able to login using my Apple ID in Firefox. Is there a URL that can enable me to send iMessage from Firefox?

Comment: Do you own a Mac or iOS Device?

Comment: Not yet -- I suspect they're building it into the iCloud web interface.

Answer (score 11):

No. iMessage (rebranded as Messages) service is only implemented on Apple hardware and it is not available for other desktop/mobile/web platforms. Apple does offer web apps for other parts of iCloud but not iMessage or FaceTime.

You need an Apple device, specifically running either iOS (iPhone, iPad, iPod touch), macOS (Mac desktops and MacBook portables) or watchOS (Apple Watch) to access Messages via native app available for each platform.

Messages is not accessible using other Web browsers such as Firefox, and not available even using Apple's own Web browser Safari.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a [jailbreakable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/336229/) iOS device, you can install the Remote Messages package.

- ## [<sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> Remote Messages](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/co.uk.beastsoft.remotemessagesios9/)

Features(from the package description):

- SMS and iMessage support
- File/media attachments
- Camera roll access
- Drafts
- Emoji support
- Message searching
- Typing notifications
- Contact pictures
- Custom Themes
- Phone status icons
- Connects to Address Book
- SSL Support and username/password authentication
- Utilises WebSockets for perfect synchronisation with device
- Runs as a background service with a small memory footprint

Installation Instructions:

1. Install the "Remote Messages (iOS 9)" package in Cydia or Sileo.
2. Navigate to "Remote Messages" in Settings.
3. Set the username and password you wish to use.
4. Slide the toggle to start the server. Allow a few seconds for this to complete. If it does not work, restart your device and try again.
5. Make sure your device is connected to the same WiFi network as your computer.
6. In the "Remote Messages" settings panel, note the IP address displayed at the top.
7. Enter the IP into the address bar of your web browser. For example: http://192.168.0.5
8. At the prompt, authenticate using the username and password you set

Clearing up some misconceptions about jailbreaking:

- Jailbreaking is 100% legal and Congress has issued a special DMCA exception allowing jailbreaking
- As long as you remember to unjailbreak before going to the Apple Store your warranty will not be affected
- Jailbreaking can easily be reverted without losing your data
- This package/tweak does not affect the security or encryption of iMessage, because it requires a physical device and "pretends" to be an actual user typing in a message

Comment: You might also note that jailbreaking is rather drastic and also voids any and all warranties.

Comment: @Cullub Properly restoring your phone to factory before taking it into Apple solves the warranty problem.

Comment: I imagine this also breaks the encryption of Messages?

Comment: @Cullub This is absolutely false. Jailbreaking may break specific warranties in certain jurisdictions, but for the most part the rule of thumb is that legal warranties aren't voided through jailbreaking. Do note that jailbreaking is illegal in certain (smaller) countries and that for example in many EU countries the warranty on the hardware stays fully intact, but (logically) this does not apply to any service and warranty for the software.

Comment: Well, here in the US it does seem to void the warranty.  Good point @23k on restoring to defaults.

Comment: This would be a fun mini-project for to be done with iPhone 4

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking#Legal_status

Comment: @Tim No, the security of iMessage is not affected because the tweak "pretends" to be an actual user typing in the message.